# How I Find My Global IP Address On Windows 10 64-bit OS ? Can I Via Using Command Prompt ? Can Anyone Help Me?

Tags: networking, system-administration

I Would Like To Find My ***Global IP*** Via Command Prompt. How I Find This ?

Comment: By global you mean Internet? You could just search what is ip in Google

Comment: Have you tried Googling? Hint: google for "whats my ip"

Comment: ya i googling and i find my global ip.. thankx #Alex.... and also thankx #Rafale #Almeida.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ipconfig -all
```

you will get enough information, I think.

regards

Answer (score 1):

The command `ipconfig` should do the trick. `ipconfig /ALL` will display more information and also currently deactivated network devices.